# Spring + Hibernate, can not read xml error

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate

I am a newbie in Spring + Hibernate, but I have worked on this problem for last one day. I still can not figure out what is the root cause, and what should I do. So, thank you in advance if any one can give me some advice.

Here is a problem, I just write a simple test class, but when I ran, there is an exception:

> ??: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh >attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error >creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource >>>>>>>[ApplicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is >org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
>   Exception in thread "main" >org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean >with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource >[ApplicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is> org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>       at com.xw.test.Test.main(Test.java:30)

And here is the class source code:

```
package com.domain;

import java.util.Date;

public class Employee {

    private Integer id;

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private java.util.Date hiredate;
    private Float salary;

    public Float getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(Float salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public java.util.Date getHiredate() {
        return hiredate;
    }
    public void setHiredate(java.util.Date hiredate) {
        this.hiredate = hiredate;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Employee( String name, String email, Date hiredate,
            Float salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.hiredate = hiredate;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Employee(){
    }
    }
```

And here is the Employee.hbm.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.domain">
   <class name="Employee" table="employee">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <generator class="native" ></generator> 
        </id>

   <property name="email" type="java.lang.String" >
        <column name="email" length="64"/>
   </property>

   <property name="hiredate" type="java.util.Date">
   <column name="hiredate" />
   </property>

   <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
   <column name="name"/>
   </property>

   <property name="salary" type="java.lang.Float">
   <column name="salary"/>
   </property>


   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And here is the ApplicationContext.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

<bean id="testService" class="com.xw.test.TestService">
    <property name="name" value="XingWang"/>
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:orcl"/>
    <property name="username" value="scott"/>
    <property name="password" value="111111"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="3"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="500"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="2"/>
    <property name="minIdle" value="1"/>
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>com/domain/Employee.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect

        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

And the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>myssh</groupId>
  <artifactId>myssh</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebRoot</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>


  </build>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
</dependency>




   <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

And here is the smiple test class source code:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.xw.test;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.domain.Employee;

/**
 * @author Administrator
 *
 */
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");

        SessionFactory sf = (SessionFactory) ac.getBean("sessionFactory");
        Session s = sf.openSession();

        Employee employee = new Employee( "aa", "aa.sohu@com", new java.util.Date(),
                (float) 234.56) ;
        Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
        s.save(employee);
        tx.commit();


    }

}
```

Thank you so much for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

The properties should be declared like below inside your sessionFactory Bean.

```
           <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
           </props>
```

so your sessionFactory bean would be like below.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
<property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
        <value>com/domain/Employee.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
           </props>
</property>
```

Comment: Hi, Mr Deendayal Garg. Thank you so much for your help. And I've modified according to your advice. But the expection is the same. By the way, is there any possible you tell me which manual I should check. I am trying to find a official manual to compare if I missed or missunderstand something, but I can not make sure which version in my case I should choose. I am sorry for that. And best wishes to you!

Answer (score 0):

sometimes there is a chance of cant pick ur config files because of compiler dont konw which file shoul it take for configuration.so for this reason u should explicitly import those config file via 2 methods as i know
1)by using class

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource(value = {"classpath:{filename-within-resource}/Employee.hbm.xml"},"classpath:{filename-within-resource}/ApplicationContext.cfg.xml")

public class CommonSolutionConfig {

}
```

2)by using xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:{filename-within-resource}/Employee.hbm.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:{filename-within-resource}/ApplicationContext.cfg.xml"/>
</beans>
```

hopefully it will solve ur problem